# Is it possible to have a password protected update site in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, p2, update-site

I have got a scenario where I have to provide my eclipse RCP application product update site links to more than 3 clients. The client will be able to update his/her eclipse plugins/features accordingly. I will be maintaining different update site links for each client.
For security reasons of the product, I had a query if eclipse provides us with any such options to prompt for username and password after the user adds the URL in the Add Repository dialog while it is validating the URL. If yes, then how to proceed with this. I have gone through few answers but no where it is mentioned on how to implement it.
It would be a great help if anyone is able to give few insights.

Comment: What did you try? If you password protect your site, for example using `.htaccess` with `AuthType Basic` or (better) `Digest`, Eclipse should ask for credentials when accessing it.

Comment: @not2savvy I was trying with ftp server, as in the URL we have to mention the username and password. But I wanted something that would be compatible with web site. I will try with what you have mentioned. Thanks for your input!